# Cómo poner un primer elemento por encima del segundo en mi código html

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando bootstrap v4.1.3 para desarrollar la visualidad de la página web y estoy usando su sistema de rejillas para acomodar los elementos. tengo la pantalla dividida en dos usando `container-fluid` y `col-6`. En el primer `col-6` tengo una serie de elementos y en el segundo `col-6` tengo una imagen. La cuestión es que deseo que los elementos que están en la primera parte debe superponerse a los que están en la segunda. De la forma que se muestra en la imagen
[image: imagen de ejemplo]
El elemento naranja se encuentra en el elemento amarillo (el primer `col-6`) y debe superponerse al elemento azul (el segundo `col-6`)

```css
.seccion {
    background-color: rgba(255, 200, 100, 80%);
    padding-left: 15rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    width: calc(100vw - 25%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h1>Encabezado</h1>
            <div class="seccion">
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>texto 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>texto 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>texto 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>texto 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>texto 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>texto 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517213849290-bbbfffdc6da3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60 1x, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517213849290-bbbfffdc6da3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60 2x">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para cambiar el orden de los elementos se usa [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). El valor debe ser `auto` o un número entero. Un elemento con mayor valor cubre a otro con menor valor así que debes especificar un número mayor que `0` y distinto de `auto`.

El problema radica entonces que tu elemento con clase `seccion` no es un elemento [posicionado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position) y por lo tanto la propiedad `z-index` no tiene efecto. El elemento no puede ser estático para que funcione y la mejor forma de lograrlo es usando `position: relative` que lo convertirá en posicionado pero lo dejará en el mismo lugar siempre que no modifiques ningún valor de posicionado como `left`, `right`, `top`, etc.

```css
.seccion {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 200, 100, 80%);
  padding-left: 15rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  width: calc(100vw - 25%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h1>Encabezado</h1>
      <div class="seccion">
        <div class="sub">
          <p>texto 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
          <p>texto 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
          <p>texto 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
          <p>texto 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
          <p>texto 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
          <p>texto 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517213849290-bbbfffdc6da3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60 1x, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517213849290-bbbfffdc6da3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60 2x">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, hoy aprendí algo nuevo :D